# How to get Binding.path in code behind (wpf project)

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, path

How can I get the "Path" value of the Binding property in my code behind?

I can see the `Binding.Path` in the debugger but I can't get the value programmatically.

[image: debugger view]

Comment: What happens when you can't get the value? You get null? An exception? Please provide some code.

Comment: i try accessing the Binding path property by this way : "e.Column.ClipboardContentBinding.Path", but there is no property "Path" for "e.Column.ClipboardContentBinding" object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast the ClipboardContentBinding property from a BindingBase to a System.Windows.Data.Binding:

```
System.Windows.Data.Binding binding = e.Column.ClipboardContentBinding as System.Windows.Data.Binding;
if(binding != null)
{
    string path = binding.Path.Path;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is the solution. (but i don't understand why i must cast the "ClipboardContentBinding" to a "System.Windows.Data.Binding" while the debuger tag "ClipboardContentBinding" already as a "System.Windows.Data.Binding" type)

Comment: Because the ClipboardContentBinding property is defined as a BindingBase which is the base class for Binding, i.e. the class's public API doesn't expose the concrete type that derives from BindingBase. The debugger displays the properties of the actual type in memory.